# How can I implement image Flip Animation in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

How can I implement image flip animation towards right. the code given below. plz help .

```
imageview.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"imag2.png"],
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"imag3.png"],
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"imag4.png"],
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"imag5.png"], 
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"imag6.png"],
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"imag7.png"], nil];

imageview.animationDuration=15.0;
imageview.animationRepeatCount=0;
[imageview startAnimating];
```

Comment: what's the problem in the way you have done?

Comment: @Will: It is only a simple animation. How can I flip images towards right one by one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for vertical flip

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    yourView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,1.0,0.0,0.0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // code to be executed when flip is completed
}];
```

for horizontal flip

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    yourView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,1.0,0.0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // code to be executed when flip is completed
}];
```

and don't forget to add QuartzCore framework to the project and importing

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: I tried this code. but i have got an error. is this due to ios 4.0?

Comment: this should work on iOS 4.0 or later, what error are exactly getting?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CATransform3DMakeRotation", referenced from:
  ___-[homeViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_1 in homeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: include the QuartzCore header file, you also have to right click "Frameworks", select "Add Existing Frameworks" and add "QuartzCore.framework".

Answer (score 2):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:imageview cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I think This code may help you.

Comment: @nila how should the images get to flip its like side by side(scrolling vertically) or like view controller Flip.?

Comment: Check this Link what you need i think its work for you http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.in/2011/01/create-image-slide-show-in-iphone-using.html